# In The Rookie, who is Nolan's secret dalliance? Can't tell because of my face blindness

Tags: character, the-rookie

I just started watching The Rookie, but my face blindness is causing me issues. I have no idea who Nolan's long-haired secret dalliance in the first episode is. At first I thought she was the bunny from the karaoke bar who offers him her phone number, but then at the end of the episode I saw her in the police parking garage being addressed by another police officer (who I think is Nolan's T.O.) and I was confused because I didn't think the bunny was a cop. Unless the bunny is actually a cop and not a cop chaser. As I said, i got extreme face blindness, so I can't remember if I saw her during another scene.

I also at one point thought she was the chief of police (the woman whose office Nolan gets prank sent to at the start), but I doubted that during the parking garage scene she would accept a subordinate talking like that.

Who is Nolan's secret dalliance?

Comment: https://www.cbr.com/rookie-nolan-lucy-romance-doom/

Comment: I haven't seen the show so I've no idea if this is the answer you're after.

Comment: Have you already thought of rewatching the episode with closed captions on?

Comment: @ToddWilcox Unfortunately the site I watched it on didn't offer that option. I live in Belgium and there is not a single streaming service available here that offers the show, so I had to make do... And yes, I know that it's piracy, but if they don't offer me a legal way to watch the show, I'll have to find alternatives. I already subscribe to 3 different streaming services.

Comment: Which episode is involved here?

Comment: @Paulie_D I've literally only watched the first episode so far to see what it's about. I liked Castle, another police show that Nathan Fillion starred in, so I wanted to check out other content with him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Lucy Chen

From a [recap](https://entertainment-focus.com/2019/03/24/the-rookie-1x01-pilot-recap/)

> The rookies went out for beers after shift and a waitress kept eyeing up Nolan. She eventually left him her number and it looked like they’d gone home together. However, it turned out that Nolan went home with Chen. The pair had been dating for a while and had to keep it secret from their colleagues.